# Any C# code to get resultset of a SQL query similar to that of SSMS output window

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, ssms

May be a dirty question. Is there a simpler way in C# code to get resultset of a SQL query similar to that of SSMS output window

Input should be accepting a SQL Statement as shown below

```
select * from table_1;
```

Ouput should be a text like that shown on SSMS output window.

```
Column1 Colum2
1       2
2       3
```

Comment: You mean displaying the resulting data in a *grid*?

Comment: The data in the code will be structured into columns by default.  Are you asking how to _display_ it?  If so, we need to know what display technology you're using at least.  Your question is very unclear.

Comment: What GUI technology are you using?

Comment: Is this a dirty question? If you include such phrases in your question, you're liable to get downvotes. Just to clear I didn't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would rather have a **console application** than deal with a WinForms or ASP.Net WebForms application, this [tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlclient) will show you how to do it, step by step. You really need to get all the details there, but this will give you an idea of how it's done in a key method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Read in all rows from the Dogs1 table and store them in a List.
/// </summary>
static void DisplayDogs()
{
    List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
    ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.masterConnectionString))
    {
    con.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Dogs1", con))
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
        int weight = reader.GetInt32(0);    // Weight int
        string name = reader.GetString(1);  // Name string
        string breed = reader.GetString(2); // Breed string
        dogs.Add(new Dog() { Weight = weight, Name = name, Breed = breed });
        }
    }
    }
    foreach (Dog dog in dogs)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(dog);
    }
}
```

Comment: the question is about dispaly.